# Parallax Scrolling Imagery on different browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, parallax

I just launched by portfolio site and was checking it out on different browsers. The underlying images becomes giant and takes up the entire screen (mainly on firefox). I run IOS Yosemite on google chrome and it looks great and works perfectly. The parallax effect is pure CSS. Let me know what you think or how I can fix this.
Thank you.

bbennettdesign.com

Comment: The parallax effect isn't working on Firefox 33.0.2, OS X 10.9.5: I can eiter scroll the start image OR the content, but not both. And the start image's turquoise dots and the hello text is quite grainy - but maybe that's intended.

Comment: Can you expand on this? The green image isn't suppose to be that big, not sure how thats happening, if I make the top layer scroll and the bottom stationary would that work? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Keith Clark's Pure CSS Parallax effect](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) and normally, you changed some items on parallax structure by oneself.

Please remove your styles and HTML markup and check it. If effect is working, test your specific codes. Because this effect work on Firefox.

> Browser support
>
> ```
> Firefox, Safari, Opera and Chrome all support this effect.
> Firefox works too but there is currently a minor issue with alignment.
> IE doesn't support preserve-3d yet (it's coming) so the parallax effect won't work. That's ok though, you should still design your
> ```
>
> content to work without the parallax effect - You know, progressive
>   enhancement and all that!

Or you can use [this.](http://davidwalsh.name/parallax)